# iOS: No account for team

Tags: ios, xcode

Человек сделал для меня проект в **XCode**, теперь мне надо там внести изменения, но я его не могу открыть. Выдаёт такую ошибку:

> No account for team "RMFZR79L68". (Add a new account in the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials.)

Я правильно понимаю, что он должен добавить меня в список разработчиков? Он утверждает, что ошибка в чём-то другом.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно определиться, с какого аккаунта вы в итоге хотите разрабатывать и распространять приложение.

Если с личного вашего, перейдите в настройках проекта в меню

`Targets -> Ваш таргет -> General -> Signing -> Team`

Там в выпадающем меню выберите `Personal Team` с вашим именем (потребуется залогиниться в ваш аккаунт Apple, а для распространения в App Store иметь подписку на Apple Developer Program). Потребуется также сменить `bundle identifier` приложения на той же странице в разделе `Identity`, так как он глобальный и не может повторяться с тем, что приложению выдал человек, создавший проект.

Если с корпоративного, которым управляет другой человек, то он должен добавить ваш Apple-аккаунт в список разработчиков на сайте Apple Developer. После этого вы в том же меню сможете выбрать из выпадающего списка название вашей компании, и менять `bundle identifier` не понадобится, если он зарегистрирован на ту же компанию.